IntelMPI incorrectly scattering data
I am working on an MPI application where I divide a global domain (of float values) into multiple tiles and distribute these across different ranks using subarrays and Scatterv for distribution.
While the application runs correctly locally using both g++ and icpc (launched with OpenMPI), it encounters problems in a cluster environment (compiled with icpc and launched with Intel MPI), where the data distributed across ranks is incorrect, although counts and displacements are verified to be correct.
Due to insufficient number of cores on my machine, I have to use --oversubscribe flag when launching the program, which I do not do in the cluster environment. As far as I know, this is the only difference, which should not make any effect here.
This issue specifically arises when the number_of_procs*4==domain_edge_size, while other configurations with different decompositions and tile sizes work fine. Despite detailed logging, with all variables related to displacements, counts and offsets being correct, I have not been able to find the cause of the error. The problem persists even after reducing the application to its smallest reproducible example, where I only create types, subarrays, scatter and gather them without any need for synchronization, indicating the issue could perhaps lie in some cluster MPI configuration.
main.cpp
#include "mpi.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

void run(std::vector<float> &out_result)  {
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int global_edge_size = 32;

    // fill the initial temperatures with some values
    std::vector<float> initial_temperature;
    for (int i = 0; i < global_edge_size * global_edge_size; i++) {
        initial_temperature.push_back(float(i));
    }

    // 1d decomposition
    // num_ranks in x and y direction
    std::array<int, 2> dims = {size, 1};
    int n_dims = 1;
    int tile_size_x = global_edge_size / size;
    int tile_size_y = global_edge_size;
    // tile with halo border
    int tile_size_with_halo_x = tile_size_x + (2 * 2);
    int tile_size_with_halo_y = tile_size_y + (2 * 2);
    int halo_zone_size = 2;

    MPI_Datatype global_tile_type_float, local_tile_type_float;
    
    // only root needs the global tile type
    if (rank == 0) {
        std::array domain_dims = {global_edge_size, global_edge_size};
        std::array tile_dims = {tile_size_y, tile_size_x};
        std::array<int, 2> start_arr = {0, 0};

        // initial datatypes to derive the resized types from
        MPI_Datatype tile_org_type_float{MPI_DATATYPE_NULL};
        MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, domain_dims.data(), tile_dims.data(), start_arr.data(), MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, &tile_org_type_float);
        MPI_Type_create_resized(tile_org_type_float, 0, 1 * sizeof(float), &global_tile_type_float);
        MPI_Type_commit(&global_tile_type_float);

        MPI_Type_free(&tile_org_type_float);
    }

    std::array<int, 2> local_tile_with_halo_dims = {tile_size_with_halo_y, tile_size_with_halo_x};
    std::array<int, 2> local_tile_dims = {tile_size_y, tile_size_x};
    std::array<int, 2> start_arr = {halo_zone_size, halo_zone_size};

    MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, local_tile_with_halo_dims.data(), local_tile_dims.data(), start_arr.data(), MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, &local_tile_type_float);
    MPI_Type_commit(&local_tile_type_float);

    // array of ones, each rank gets one tile
    auto counts = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
    std::fill_n(counts.get(), size, 1);

    auto displacements = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        int row = i / dims[0];
        int col = i % dims[0];
        displacements[i] = (row * tile_size_y * global_edge_size) + (col * tile_size_x);
    }

    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("displacements: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            printf("%d, ", displacements[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    std::vector<float> tile_temps(tile_size_with_halo_x * tile_size_with_halo_y);

    MPI_Scatterv(initial_temperature.data(), counts.get(), displacements.get(), global_tile_type_float, tile_temps.data(), 1, local_tile_type_float, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    // synchronization only for printing purposes
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("[%d] printing %dx%d grid (initial temperature)\n", rank, global_edge_size, global_edge_size);
        for (int r = 0; r < global_edge_size; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < global_edge_size; c++) {
                printf("%f ", initial_temperature[r * global_edge_size + c]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    // print received data from each rank
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if (rank == i) {
            printf("[%d] printing %dx%d grid\n", rank, tile_size_with_halo_x, tile_size_with_halo_y);
            for (int r = halo_zone_size; r < tile_size_y + halo_zone_size; r++) {
                for (int c = halo_zone_size; c < tile_size_x + halo_zone_size; c++) {
                    printf("%f ", tile_temps[r * tile_size_with_halo_x + c]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int size, rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    std::vector<float> result;
    run(result);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD          17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(MPI_CXX_SKIP_MPICXX ON)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED COMPONENTS CXX)

add_executable(main ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main MPI::MPI_CXX)

cmake -Bbuild -S.
cmake --build build --config Release
mpirun -np 8 ./main

On the picture is the debug print of the incorrect data distribution. My result (top) is different from the reference (bottom) array, although they should be identical. The differences persist when inspecting the local arrays from the individual ranks, so the issue is not in the MPI_Gatherv.
I am happy to provide any further information or answer regarding the code or cluster environment.
Incorrect data distribution

Did you copy & paste your actual code? I don't believe the line void HeatSolver::run(std::vector<float, float &outResult) {

Does mpirun --mca coll ^tuned ... solve your issue? If not, please edit your question and add a [mcve].

@VictorEijkhout Sorry, the line was originally void HeatSolver::run(std::vector<float, AlignedAllocator<float>> &outResult), since it uses uses custom allocator for later OpenMP opitimization. However, I ruled it out as the potential cause of the problem so I (sloppily) removed it.

@GillesGouaillardet I tried to reduce the code as much as possible. The types need to be resized and the variables were kept for legibility. Which code should I remove to make it a minimal reproducible example?
To your question, no, mpirun --mca coll ^tuned does not solve the issue as the cluster IntelMPI does not recognize this option.

the title of the question reads Open MPI but you are using Intel MPI? [mcve] implies the program is minimal but yet complete so it can be compiled and run to evidence the issue, in this case, you will need to add some code around.

@GillesGouaillardet I fixed the minimal reproducible example so it is a standalone launchable program. The issue manifests only in Intel MPI.

Thanks! I will have a look.how many MPI tasks do you run?

@GillesGouaillardet I launch it with 8 tasks. Also added my CMakeLists.txt and all the commands I use into the post.

I can confirm this is an Intel MPI bug (!). No issue with Open MPI nor MPICH. I will simplify the code and report it to the Intel MPI forum. Meanwhile, you can resize the datatype to 4*sizeof(float) and use a simple MPI_Scatter().

@GillesGouaillardet Thanks for confirmation, I am already working on the submission for Intel MPI forum, will post the link here as soon as possible.

I suggest you make your program pure C and use integer instead of float, hard code as much as possible and make it self tested instead of printing. for example I did int expected = rank*4 + (c-haloZoneSize) + (r-haloZoneSize)*32; if (expected != (tile_temps[r * tile_size_with_halo_x + c]) MPI_Abort(..);

As Gilles confirmed, it is most likely an Intel MPI bug and the discussion will probably continue on the forum.
